Add NSView to custom parameter in FxPlug - Swift
I'm developing a plugin for Final Cut Pro, and need help on the UI part. FCPX plugins are swift application bundled in a FxPlug wrapper. The UI is made of parameter views packed together, custom parameter views can be created in order to display a logo or a custom element:

I followed the official Apple documentation about FxPlug and managed to get regular parameters working (sliders, integers, etc...). Easy.
However, I can't get a custom parameter working. Parameters needs to be instantiate in the addParameters method:
func addParameters() throws {

        let paramAPI = _apiManager!.api(for: FxParameterCreationAPI_v5.self) as! FxParameterCreationAPI_v5
        
        // Create the custom parameter   
        paramAPI.addCustomParameter(withName: "Logo", parameterID: 2, defaultValue: NSData(), parameterFlags: FxParameterFlags(kFxParameterFlag_CUSTOM_UI))
    }

I can then link the custom parameter to a NSView in the createView method:
func createView(forParameterID parameterID: UInt32) -> NSView? {

        if parameterID == 2 {
            // Instantiate custom view with the initial frame size
            let myCustomView = CustomView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
                        
            // Return the view to be managed by the host application
            return myCustomView
        }

        // Return nil for any parameter IDs without custom view
        return nil
    }

My CustomView is a simple Cocoa class (for testing purpose):
import Cocoa
import AppKit

class SimpleTestView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
    
}

The plugin crash when trying to access the UI, with the following error:
<Studio_UI_XPC_Service.SimpleTestView 0x120821c60> has reached dealloc but still has a super view. Super views strongly reference their children, so this is being over-released, or has been over-released in the past.

How do I prevent this crash when creating a custom view for a custom parameter?

My computer isn't set up for FxPlugin development, so I can't reproduce your issue, but it looks like you need to hold on to a reference to your CustomView. The error message says it is being deallocated unexpectedly, and the documentation for createView(forParameterID:) says:
NOTE: The object returned by this method should not be autoreleased. It should be allocated by the method, and will be released by the caller.

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fxcustomparameterviewhost_v2/3378466-createview)
Since Swift uses automatic reference counting (ARC), objects are always autoreleased as soon as the reference count reaches 0. It seems like the plugin that calls the method does not use reference counting, so when your method returns, the reference count hits 0 and the object is deallocated.
You can fix this by assigning the view to a property of the class that implements createView(forParameterID:):
class ViewProvider: FxCustomParameterViewHost_v2 {
    private var customView: CustomView?

    func createView(forParameterID parameterID: UInt32) -> NSView! {
        if parameterID == 2 {
            customView = CustomView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
            return customView!
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}

This will prevent the reference count from going to zero after the method returns, and the view won't be deallocated.

Thank you! This fixed the main issue, tho I got the following error Got an unexpected pixel format in the IOSurface: 0x52476841. Not sure why, I'll investigate. The plugin isn't crashing anymore.
